# LOOP IN DATAFRAME PANDAS

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a for loop which will check first column degree and then column score.

```
IF degree > 90 AND score < 90 THEN create new column say TRUE ELSE say FALSE.
```

So result in new column `RESULT` should be: TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE.

THANKS

```py
# dictionary of lists 
dict = {'degree': [90, 40, 80, 98], 
        'score':[70, 70, 70, 70]} 

# creating a dataframe from a dictionary  
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Code and Error Message

```py
result = [] 
for i,j in df.itertuples(index=False): 
  if i > 90: 
    if j <90 result.append('ISTRUE') 
  else: result.append('ISFALSE') 
df['RESULT'] = result
```

> File "", line 5 if j <90 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Hi stano and welcome to SO. Your conditions for your loop seem to get you near your answer. Did you try to write a for-loop by yourself? What code did you use and what error message did it produce?

Comment: result = []
for i,j in df.itertuples(index=False):
    
    if i > 90:
        if j <90
         result.append('ISTRUE')
    else:
         result.append('ISFALSE')

df['RESULT'] = result           
            



  File "<ipython-input-103-637f31d0ba23>", line 5
    if j <90
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You are missing an `:` after `j < 90`.

Comment: import pandas as pd



In [2]:


# dictionary of lists 
dict = {'degree': [90, 40, 80, 98], 
        'score':[70, 70, 70, 100]} 
​
# creating a dataframe from a dictionary  
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)



In [5]:


result = [] 
for i,j in df.itertuples(index=False): 
    if i > 90: 
        if j <90: result.append('ISTRUE')
    else: result.append('NOTTRUE')
df['RESULT'] = result 

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: thank you for your answer. still givin me error. please can you look into it?

Comment: Hey stano. Please stop posting your code as comment. You can edit your question by clicking on `edit` right under your post. Please edit your existing question according to your code.

Comment: why if i set value to 100 it shows me error. i want to save for every check  one result.so always should be 4 results in new column saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, so I am guessing. Your desired output looks like this:

```
degree score RESULT
90     70    TRUE
40     70    FALSE
80     70    FALSE
98     70    TRUE
```

Therefore your created loop

```py
for i,j in df.itertuples(index=False): 
  if i > 90: 
    if j < 90:
      result.append('ISTRUE') 
  else: 
      result.append('ISFALSE')
```

has several issues.

1. Looping over `i` and `j` gives you `i*j` executions. And therefore your resulting list is of length `i*j`.
2. I suppose your first `if` condition should be `>=` instead of `>`.

Your code should look like:

```py
result = []
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
  if df['degree'][i] >= 90 and df['score'][i] < 90:
      result.append('ISTRUE') 
  else: 
      result.append('ISFALSE') 
df['RESULT'] = result
```

I'm not very familiar with python, so I guess there are more pythonic ways of getting your task done. But perhaps this gives you a possible solution.